# Como atualizar estoque magento consumindo um arquivo CSV

Tags: php, sql, magento

estou utilizando um módulo de sincronismo de estoque manual criado pela BRTSync, porém preciso realizar um processo de sincronismo automática, por exemplo, consumindo os campos de um CSV já gerados por um outro software de duas em duas horas. Já tenho o arquivo de estoque, preciso inserir ele automáticamente no banco de dados do magento, alguma idéia?

O arquivo que é utilizado no sincronismo manual seria este:

```
<?php
class Bertholdo_Sync_Adminhtml_SyncestoqueController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    protected function _initAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout()->_setActiveMenu('sync/adminhtml_syncestoque');
        return $this;
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->_initAction();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    public function importacaoCsvAction()
    {
        set_time_limit(0);

        $inicio = 0;
        $fim = 0;
        $msgRetorno = "";
        $linhasFile = array();

        $csvEstoque = $_FILES['file_upload']['name'];
        $tipoFile = $_FILES['file_upload']['type'];

        $objBD_read = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core/read');

        $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
        $core_config_data = $resource->getTableName('core_config_data');

        $helper = Mage::helper('sync/data');
        $inicio = $helper->execucao();

        try
        {
            if ($this->getRequest()->getPost())
            {
                if( !empty($csvEstoque) && ( ($tipoFile == "text/csv") || ($tipoFile == "application/vnd.ms-excel") ) )
                {
                    // SALVANDO O ARQUIVO

                    $uploaderFile = new Varien_File_Uploader('file_upload');
                    $uploaderFile->setAllowedExtensions(array());
                    $uploaderFile->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
                    $uploaderFile->setFilesDispersion(false);

                    $uploaderFilepath = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'Bertholdo' . DS . 'importcsv' . DS ;
                    $filepath = $uploaderFilepath.$csvEstoque;

                    // CRIANDO E VERIFICANDO O DIRETÓRIO

                    if (file_exists($filepath)) 
                    {
                        unlink("$filepath");
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        mkdir("$uploaderFilepath", 0777, true);
                    }

                    $uploaderFile->save( $uploaderFilepath, $csvEstoque );

                    // LEITURA DO CSV

                    if ( ($handle = fopen($filepath, "r")) !== FALSE )
                    {
                        $row = 0;
                        while ( ($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ";")) !== FALSE )
                        {               
                            $linhasFile[$row] = $data;
                            $row++;
                        }
                        fclose($handle);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $message = $this->__("Return: ERROR - Reading CSV file.");
                        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($message);                        
                    }

                    // PERCENTUAL DE ATUALIZAÇÃO DE ESTOQUE

                    $configModulo = $objBD_read->query("SELECT value FROM $core_config_data WHERE path LIKE '%sync/options_sync/%'")->fetchAll();

                    // ATUALIZANDO PRODUTOS

                    $qtdLinhas = count($linhasFile);
                    for($i = 1; $i < $qtdLinhas; $i++)
                    {
                        // PULANDO LINHAS DE LIXO

                        if (empty($linhasFile[$i][0])) continue;

                        // CAMPOS DO CSV PADRÃO

                        $descricao_produto = $helper->limpaString($linhasFile[$i][0]);
                        $codigo_sku_sistema_legado = $linhasFile[$i][1];
                        $preco_produto = $linhasFile[$i][2];
                        $preco_promo_produto = $linhasFile[$i][3];
                        $estoque_atual = $linhasFile[$i][4];
                        $percentual_atualizacao = $linhasFile[$i][5];

                        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
                        $product_id = $product->getIdBySku($codigo_sku_sistema_legado);

                        // CASO O USUÁRIO PREENCHA O CSV COM O VALOR DO PERCENTUAL O MESMO SERÁ APLICADO NO ESTOQUE

                        if (empty($percentual_atualizacao))
                        {
                            $qtd = round(($estoque_atual * ($configModulo[3]['value']/100)));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $qtd = round(($estoque_atual * ($percentual_atualizacao/100)));
                        }

                        // 1 - EM ESTOQUE, 0 - ESGOTADO

                        $estoque = ($qtd > 0) ? 1 : 0;

                        try
                        {
                            // VERIFICA SE O PRODUTO É NOVO OU NÃO

                            if(empty($product_id))
                            {                       
                                $product->setAttributeSetId(4);
                                $product->setTypeId('simple');
                                $product->setUrlKey(str_replace(" ", "-", $descricao_produto));
                                $product->setSku($codigo_sku_sistema_legado);
                                $product->setName($descricao_produto);

                                // TODO PRODUTO NOVO É INSERIDO NA CATEGORIA PRINCIPAL

                                $product->setCategoryIds(array($configModulo[1]['value']));
                                $product->setWebsiteIds(array(1));
                                $product->setDescription($descricao_produto);
                                $product->setShortDescription($descricao_produto);
                                $product->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
                                $product->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now'));
                                $product->setTaxClassId(0);
                                $product->setWeight(1);

                                // 1 - HABILITADO, 2 - DESABILITADO

                                $product->setStatus(2);

                                $product->setPrice($preco_produto);
                                $product->setMsrp($preco_produto);
                                $product->setSpecialPrice($preco_promo_produto);

                                // SALVA ESTOQUE

                                $stockData = array('qty' => $qtd, 'is_in_stock' => $estoque);
                                $product->setStockData($stockData);
                                $product->save();

                                unset($product, $stockData);

                                Mage::getSingleton('core/cache')->flush();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $loadProduct = $product->load($product_id);
                                $loadProduct->setPrice($preco_produto);
                                $loadProduct->setMsrp($preco_produto);
                                $product->setSpecialPrice($preco_promo_produto);

                                // ATUALIZA ESTOQUE

                                $stockData = array('qty' => $qtd, 'is_in_stock' => $estoque);
                                $loadProduct->setStockData($stockData);
                                $loadProduct->save();

                                unset($product, $loadProduct, $stockData, $product_id);

                                Mage::getSingleton('core/cache')->flush();
                            }                       
                        }
                        catch (Exception $ex)
                        {
                            //Zend_Debug::dump($ex->getMessage());
                            //Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($ex->getMessage());
                        }
                    }

                    $fim = $helper->execucao();

                    $message = $this->__("Return: Import successful. <br/> Time: %s minute", number_format(($fim-$inicio)));
                    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess($message);
                }
                else
                {
                    $message = $this->__("Return: ERROR - Reading CSV file.");
                    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($message);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $message = $this->__("Return: ERROR - Sending form data.");
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($message);
            }                                   
        }
        catch (Exception $e) 
        {
            $message = $e->getMessage();
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($message);
        }
        $this->_redirect('*/*');
    }

    public function exportacaoCsvAction()
    {
        $csvEstoque = "sync_estoque_produtos.csv";

        $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
        $core_config_data = $resource->getTableName('core_config_data');

        $objBD_read = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core/read');
        $helper = Mage::helper('sync/data');        

        try
        {
            if ($this->getRequest()->getPost())
            {
                // PERCENTUAL DE ATUALIZAÇÃO DE ESTOQUE E CATEGORIA DE PRODUTO PADRÃO

                $configModulo = $objBD_read->query("SELECT value FROM $core_config_data WHERE path LIKE '%sync/options_sync/%'")->fetchAll();

                // COLEÇÃO DOS PRODUTOS BASEADO NA CATEGORIA E QTY ESTOQUE DEFINIDA NAS CONFIGURAÇÕES DO MÓDULO

                $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($configModulo[1]['value']);
                $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                                                               ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name','sku','price','special_price','qty'))                                   
                                                               ->addCategoryFilter($category)                   
                                                               ->joinField( 
                                                                            'qty', 
                                                                            'cataloginventory/stock_item', 
                                                                            'qty', 
                                                                            'product_id=entity_id', 
                                                                            '{{table}}.stock_id=1', 'left'
                                                                );

                // SE ESTIVER VAZIO NÃO APLICO O FILTRO DE QUANTIDADE E TRAGO TODO MUNDO

                if (!empty($configModulo[2]['value']))
                {
                    $collection->getSelect()->where("at_qty.qty >= {$configModulo[2]['value']}");
                }

                //Mage::log($collection->getSelect()->__toString());

                // CRIANDO O DIRETÓRIO

                $uploaderFilepath = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'Bertholdo' . DS . 'importcsv' . DS ;
                $filepath = $uploaderFilepath.$csvEstoque;

                // CRIANDO E VERIFICANDO O DIRETÓRIO

                if (file_exists($filepath)) 
                {
                    unlink("$filepath");
                } 
                else 
                {
                    mkdir("$uploaderFilepath", 0777, true);
                }

                // CABEÇALHO DO CSV

                $fp = fopen($filepath, 'w');
                fputcsv($fp, array("descricao_produto;codigo_sku_sistema_legado;preco_produto;preco_promo_produto;estoque_atual;percentual_atualizacao"));

                foreach ($collection as $product)
                {
                    // TIVE QUE REMOVER OS ESPAÇOS DA DESCRIÇÃO DO PRODUTO POIS O CSV NÃO RECONHECE COMO UMA INFORMAÇÃO SÓ

                    $descricao_produto = substr(str_replace(" ", "_", $helper->limpaString($product->getName())),0,15) . "...";                 
                    $codigo_sku_sistema_legado = $product->getSku();

                    // COMO O VALOR VEM NO FORMATO X.000 TIVE QUE APLICAR A DIVISÃO PARA REMOVER O FORMATO DO MAGENTO

                    $preco_produto = ($product->getPrice()/1);
                    $preco_promo_produto = ($product->getSpecialPrice()/1);
                    $estoque_atual = ($product->getQty()/1);

                    // APLICANDO OS 100% SE O PRODUTO NÃO FOR MODIFICADO O MESMO CONTINUA COM SEU ANTIGO VALOR DE ESTOQUE

                    $percentual_atualizacao = 100;

                    fputcsv($fp, array($descricao_produto.';'.$codigo_sku_sistema_legado.';'.$preco_produto.';'.$preco_promo_produto.';'.$estoque_atual.';'.$percentual_atualizacao));
                }

                $helper->download($filepath);
                fclose($fp);

                exit;
            }
            else
            {
                $message = $this->__("Return: ERROR - Sending form data.");
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($message);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception $e) 
        {
            $message = $e->getMessage();
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($message);
        }
        $this->_redirect('*/*');
    }
}
?>
```

o CSV contém apenas estas colunas:
descricao_produto;codigo_sku_sistema_legado;preco_produto;qtd_estoque_atual;novo_estoque;percentual_atualizacao

o arquivo de sincronismoauto.php, seria isso:

```
<?php
class Bertholdo_Sync_Adminhtml_SyncestoqueController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    protected function _initAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout()->_setActiveMenu('sync/adminhtml_syncestoque');
        return $this;
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->_initAction();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
    public function importacaoCsvAction()
    {
        set_time_limit(0);

        $inicio = 0;
        $fim = 0;
        $msgRetorno = "";
        $linhasFile = array();

        $csvEstoque = $_FILES['file_upload']['sync_estoque_produtos.csv'];
        $tipoFile = $_FILES['file_upload']['text/csv'];

        $objBD_read = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core/read');

        $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
        $core_config_data = $resource->getTableName('core_config_data');

        $helper = Mage::helper('sync/data');
        $inicio = $helper->execucao();

        try
        {
            if ($this->getRequest()->getPost())
            {
                if( !empty($csvEstoque) && ( ($tipoFile == "text/csv") || ($tipoFile == "application/vnd.ms-excel") ) )
                {
                    // SALVANDO O ARQUIVO

                    $uploaderFile = new Varien_File_Uploader('file_upload');
                    $uploaderFile->setAllowedExtensions(array());
                    $uploaderFile->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
                    $uploaderFile->setFilesDispersion(false);

                    $uploaderFilepath = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'Bertholdo' . DS . 'importcsv' . DS ;
                    $filepath = $uploaderFilepath.$csvEstoque;

                    // CRIANDO E VERIFICANDO O DIRETÓRIO

                    if (file_exists($filepath)) 
                    {
                        unlink("$filepath");
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        mkdir("$uploaderFilepath", 0777, true);
                    }

                    $uploaderFile->save( $uploaderFilepath, $csvEstoque );

                    // LEITURA DO CSV

                    if ( ($handle = fopen($filepath, "r")) !== FALSE )
                    {
                        $row = 0;
                        while ( ($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ";")) !== FALSE )
                        {               
                            $linhasFile[$row] = $data;
                            $row++;
                        }
                        fclose($handle);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $message = $this->__("Return: ERROR - Reading CSV file.");
                        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($message);                        
                    }

                    // PERCENTUAL DE ATUALIZAÇÃO DE ESTOQUE

                    $configModulo = $objBD_read->query("SELECT value FROM $core_config_data WHERE path LIKE '%sync/options_sync/%'")->fetchAll();

                    // ATUALIZANDO PRODUTOS

                    $qtdLinhas = count($linhasFile);
                    for($i = 1; $i < $qtdLinhas; $i++)
                    {
                        // PULANDO LINHAS DE LIXO

                        if (empty($linhasFile[$i][0])) continue;

                        // CAMPOS DO CSV PADRÃO

                        $descricao_produto = $helper->limpaString($linhasFile[$i][0]);
                        $codigo_sku_sistema_legado = $linhasFile[$i][1];
                        $preco_produto = $linhasFile[$i][2];
                        $preco_promo_produto = $linhasFile[$i][3];
                        $qtd_estoque_atual = $linhasFile[$i][4];
                        $novo_estoque = $linhasFile[$i][5];
                        $percentual_atualizacao = $linhasFile[$i][6];

                        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
                        $product_id = $product->getIdBySku($codigo_sku_sistema_legado);

                        // CASO O USUÁRIO PREENCHA O CSV COM O VALOR DO PERCENTUAL O MESMO SERÁ APLICADO NO ESTOQUE

                        if (empty($percentual_atualizacao))
                        {
                            $qtd = round(($novo_estoque * ($configModulo[3]['value']/100)));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $qtd = round(($novo_estoque * ($percentual_atualizacao/100)));
                        }

                        // 1 - EM ESTOQUE, 0 - ESGOTADO

                        $estoque = ($qtd > 0) ? 1 : 0;

                        try
                        {
                            // VERIFICA SE O PRODUTO É NOVO OU NÃO

                            if(empty($product_id))
                            {                       
                                $product->setAttributeSetId(4);
                                $product->setTypeId('simple');
                                $product->setUrlKey(str_replace(" ", "-", $descricao_produto));
                                $product->setSku($codigo_sku_sistema_legado);
                                $product->setName($descricao_produto);

                                // TODO PRODUTO NOVO É INSERIDO NA CATEGORIA PRINCIPAL

                                $product->setCategoryIds(array($configModulo[1]['value']));
                                $product->setWebsiteIds(array(1));
                                $product->setDescription($descricao_produto);
                                $product->setShortDescription($descricao_produto);
                                $product->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
                                $product->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now'));
                                $product->setTaxClassId(0);
                                $product->setWeight(1);

                                // 1 - HABILITADO, 2 - DESABILITADO

                                $product->setStatus(2);

                                $product->setPrice($preco_produto);
                                $product->setMsrp($preco_produto);
                                $product->setSpecialPrice($preco_promo_produto);

                                // SALVA ESTOQUE

                                $stockData = array('qty' => $qtd, 'is_in_stock' => $estoque);
                                $product->setStockData($stockData);
                                $product->save();

                                unset($product, $stockData);

                                Mage::getSingleton('core/cache')->flush();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $loadProduct = $product->load($product_id);
                                $loadProduct->setPrice($preco_produto);
                                $loadProduct->setMsrp($preco_produto);
                                $product->setSpecialPrice($preco_promo_produto);

                                // ATUALIZA ESTOQUE

                                $stockData = array('qty' => $qtd, 'is_in_stock' => $estoque);
                                $loadProduct->setStockData($stockData);
                                $loadProduct->save();

                                unset($product, $loadProduct, $stockData, $product_id);

                                Mage::getSingleton('core/cache')->flush();
                            }                       
                        }
                        catch (Exception $ex)
                        {
                            //Zend_Debug::dump($ex->getMessage());
                            //Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($ex->getMessage());
                        }
                    }

                    $fim = $helper->execucao();

                    $message = $this->__("Return: Import successful. <br/> Time: %s minute", number_format(($fim-$inicio)));
                    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess($message);
                }
                else
                {
                    $message = $this->__("Return: ERROR - Reading CSV file.");
                    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($message);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $message = $this->__("Return: ERROR - Sending form data.");
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($message);
            }                                   
        }
        catch (Exception $e) 
        {
            $message = $e->getMessage();
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($message);
        }
        $this->_redirect('*/*');
    }
}
?>
```

Deixei apenas a função de importar, deixando a captura de um arquivo na própria raiz de nome padrão e hardcode. A dúvida seria também no inicio deste aquivo requer alguma autenticação?!

Alguma ideia de como posso fazer no magento para isso rodar automáticamente? E como

Answer (score 1):

Você pode passar o método que consome o CSV para uma model, e criar um cronjob dentro do Magento para rodar esse método conforme o tempo que você precisar.
Exemplo:
No seu arquivo config.xml do módulo criar uma tag fora da tag global:

```
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <mycompany_mymodule>
            <schedule><cron_expr>*/10 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
            <run><model>mycompany_mymodule/observer::importproduct</model></run>
        </mycompany_mymodule>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

Sendo assim ele vai rodar o método importProduct da model observer, do modulo MyModule a cada 10 minutos.

Comment: Olá @guerra Obrigado pelas informações. Confesso que não entendi muito bem ainda, inserindo estas tags time e chamada de função no config.xml seria a chamada da cronjob? Como isso funciona pelo magento? Utilizo o mesmo em um windows server infelizmente. Tirando isso vi que esta chamando a func importproduct, onde eu declaro todo o seu fincionamento? Como faço a chamado do .php que a contem? tks

Comment: Olá, você tem um modulo certo? O Bertholdo_Sync, você vai pegar esse método da controller que já faz o serviço, vai deixar ele dinamico de forma que ele consiga fazer oq tem q fazer toda vez q for executado, e vai mandar ele pra uma model pois ele está em uma controller. Sendo assim, você vai configurar no config.xml do modulo essa "crontab" onde vai definir as informações pedidas, como o nome do modulo o nome da model o método etc, e o tempo de execução, seu magento tem um arquivo que chama "cron.sh" esse arquivo deve estar na crontab do servidor para ser executado a cada 10 min

Comment: Esse arquivo vai lidar com as crons do magento, não sei como funciona crontab no windows server nem se ele executa shellscript, mas além disso o magento usa essa cron dele para outrar atividades importantes para a loja, como enviar e-mail

Comment: Entendido @guerra Adicionei na pergunta como ficaria meu arquivo sincronismoauto.php por exemplo, simplesmente peguei a função de import e isolei, peguei o arquivo de forma hardcode no mesmo diretório, podes verificar se está correto? Este arquivo usa autenticação de usuário? pergunto isso porque não sei o que são as funcs _initAction e indexAction.

Comment: Na verdade você não deve usar dessa forma, vou melhorar minha resposta.

Comment: Ok @Guerra aguardo seus comentários, realmente to perdido neste tema. tks